# Flutter. When I fetch data from API showing StatusCode 403(Failed to load post)?

Tags: flutter, api

eg: details about the questions ..........................................................................
When I want to fetch multiple objects from an array showing status code 403(Failed to load post).and API having a header key I have implemented it also. but showing failed to load post status code 403.

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "7 banners found",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1635945056.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "81",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "0",
            "updated": "2021-11-03 06:10:56"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "image": "https://www.sofikart.com/admin/upload/app_banner/1642082634.jpeg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "product_id": "111",
            "url": null,
            "status": "Active",
            "ordering": "1",
            "updated": "2021-10-28 04:53:26"
        }
    ]
}

controller
-----------

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/model/post.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

final String url = 'https://www.sofikart.com/MobileApi/banners';

Future<List<Post>> fetchPost() async {

  final response = await http.get(
    url, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'SOFIKART-*2021#',},);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
    final result = json.decode(response.body);

    List<Post> posts =
    result.map<Post>((model) => new Post.fromJson(model)).toList();
    return posts;

  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

Future<String> saveNetworkImageToPhoto(String url, String title,
    {bool useCache: true}) async {
  var data = await getNetworkImageData(url, useCache: useCache);
  var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: data, title: title);
  return filePath;
}

class ImagePickerSaver {
  static saveFile({fileData, String title}) {}
}

getNetworkImageData(String url, {booluseCache, bool
useCache}) {
}
```

### model

```
    // To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Post welcomeFromJson(String str) => Post.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Post data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Post {
  Post({
    this.status,
    this.msg,
    this.data,
  });

  int status;
  String msg;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
    status: json["status"],
    msg: json["msg"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  String get catId => null;

  get image => null;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "msg": msg,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.catId,
    this.productId,
    this.url,
    this.status,
    this.ordering,
    this.updated,
  });

  String id;
  String image;
  String catId;
  String productId;
  dynamic url;
  String status;
  String ordering;
  DateTime updated;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    image: json["image"],
    catId: json["cat_id"],
    productId: json["product_id"],
    url: json["url"],
    status: json["status"],
    ordering: json["ordering"],
    updated: DateTime.parse(json["updated"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "image": image,
    "cat_id": catId,
    "product_id": productId,
    "url": url,
    "status": status,
    "ordering": ordering,
    "updated": updated.toIso8601String(),
  };
}
```

### home

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/Controller/postController.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/model/post.dart';
import 'package:fm_sidharth/page/postdetails.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<List<Post>> posts;
  _HomePageState() {
    posts = fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
        future: posts,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                PostDetails(snapshot.data[index])),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data[index].catId,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 22,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                            image: snapshot.data[index].image,
                            placeholder: 'assets/images/noimage.png',
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                                onPressed: () {

                                },
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  saveNetworkImageToPhoto(
                                      snapshot.data[index].image,snapshot.data[index].catId).then((value){

                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too some times, I think this about restrict that google set on you country. please use a proxy. I hope my answer helping to you :)

Comment: I have implemented other api also it works but it's shwoing status code 403(Failed to load post).

Comment: can you please test it in pot man ? and tell me about the result

Comment: yes i have tested above i've mentioned api responses.